# Inverting the bits of an even number in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

A girl writes N numbers on the board (odd and even numbers) and then, she modifies only even numbers and inverts its binary representation (from the left to the right ) and replaces each even number. Write a code for the same.

```
0 <= n <= 10^7
```

I made a code for this, where my partial code looks like this:

```
            int a[100000];
            while ( t != 0 )   // t is the number in which input is taken
            {
                k = t & 1;
                if ( k == 1 )               
                a[i] = 0;    // a is the array in which bits of new number will be stored
                else
                a[i] = 1;
                i++;
                t = t >> 1; 
            }
            for ( j = i; j >= 0; j-- )
            {
                if (a[j] == 1)
                {
                     num = num + pow(2,j)*a[j];   // num is the number to be formed
                }
            }
                cout<<num<<"\n";
```

But my answer comes out to be wrong for some values, for example for 8, it outputs 7. What is wrong with this? Thanks!

Problem link:

http://www.spoj.com/problems/EC_CONB/

Edit: ( In response to Pete's answer )

```
            while ( t != 0 )
            {
                k = t & 1;
                if ( k == 1 )               
                a[i] = 0;
                else
                {
                    a[i] = 1;
                    num = num + pow(2,i);
                }
                i++;
                t = t >> 1; 
            }
            cout<<num<<"\n"; 
        }
```

This still shows the same problem, outputs the value of 8 as 7.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you do it this way rather than use the `~` operator to invert the bits?

Comment: 8 is 1000 so 7 is correct i.e. 0111.  What value were you expecting?

Comment: I am sorry, but here is the link of the problem I am trying to solve. http://www.spoj.com/problems/EC_CONB/. Here, the sample cases are something else.

Comment: The question on that site is poorly worded. You're not supposed to invert it at all, you're supposed to reverse it.

Comment: @harold (in response to deleted comment) 10 is 1010B, 'invert its binary representation from left to right' gives 0101B = 5, 8 is 100B gives 001B = 1, 2 is 10B inverted left to right gives 01B = 1. Yes, it's poorly worded. but poorly worded requirements and a sample input and output are pretty par for the course in software development.

Comment: @ClickRick they want "write down bits in the opposite direction" rather than "flip each individual bit".

Comment: "a is the array in which bits of new number will be stored". You seem to expect a 100000 bits number, well beyond the range of 0..10⁷ (which is just a bit more than 23 bits). Better safe than sorry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem actually wants you to reverse the bits not invert them. So the part where you check `if k == 1`, and putting 0 instead is not correct, because that inverts the bits.

What you need to do is reverse the ordering of the bits as follows:

```
1000 (8)  -> 0001 (1)
1010 (10) -> 0101 (5)
```

Sample code based on your code:

```
while (t != 0)
{
    k = t & 1;
    // push the output array to the left 
    num <<= 1;
    // add the read bit to the beginning of the output array
    num += k;
    t = t >> 1;
}
```

Explanation:

The basic idea is that we read bits from the input number one-by-one, and push them to the beginning of the output number.

Below is a trace of reversing a number (1011) at each iteration:

```
iterations    0       1      2     3    4
input         1011    101    10    1    0
output        0       1      11    110  1101
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks a lot. However, can you please add some comments to the above code, I am new to bitwise operators and doesn't seem to understand them properly. If you do so, it will be a great help to me. thanks. :)

Comment: I have added a couple of comments to the code and an explanation at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be reading `a[i]` after incrementing `i`, so the behaviour is undefined.

Instead of creating an array, accumulate the result in the first loop.

Comment: I updated my answer, and wrote the new code, but it still has the same problem.

Comment: @JohnYad Is your code adding a 1 where there is a 1 in the original, or a 0? Is it reversing the bits or inverting them?

Comment: My code is adding a 1 when there is a 0 and 0 if there is a 1. And it is inversing the bits and not inverting them.

Comment: @JohnYad the question is worded poorly and should use 'reverse' rather than 'invert from left to right', but if you look at the examples, reversing is what it asks for. Inverting each bit in place doesn't matter whether you read left to right or do it all in one.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays? Loops? Not necessary.

Reversing the number like that is equivalent to completely reversing the integer and then right-justifying it, like this (not tested)

```
// reverse from http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ReverseParallel
// swap odd and even bits
v = ((v >> 1) & 0x55555555) | ((v & 0x55555555) << 1);
// swap consecutive pairs
v = ((v >> 2) & 0x33333333) | ((v & 0x33333333) << 2);
// swap nibbles ... 
v = ((v >> 4) & 0x0F0F0F0F) | ((v & 0x0F0F0F0F) << 4);
// swap bytes
v = ((v >> 8) & 0x00FF00FF) | ((v & 0x00FF00FF) << 8);
// swap 2-byte long pairs
v = ( v >> 16             ) | ( v               << 16);
// right-justify
v /= v & -v;
```

`v` should be an `uint32_t`.